# Enter text in Datepicker textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQueryUI to add a datepicker to a textfield. It all works fine, but because of this i'm not able to type any text into the textfield. I can only add a date through the datepicker.

But i want users to be able to also enter things like `NOW`  in the textfield. But currently entering manual text is blocked as you can see in this example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kugzd/

Is there anyway to change this behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `constrainInput: false` to your datepicker option

```
$(function() {
    $('.date').datepicker({
        constrainInput: false
    });
});
```

Check the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-constrainInput)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Kugzd/2/

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `constraintInput` option (as noted by another answer), consider combining the datepicker along with [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library, which allows you to work with words and expressions such as  `today`, `tomorrow`, `next Tuesday` and turn them into dates.